# Serverless and Terraform - configurations files mishmash

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I'm wondering how to efficiently combine 'static' json configuration files with the dynamic configurations that terraform returns

Simple structure

```
/services
  /serviceA
    configuration.json
    IConfiguration.ts
    ...
  /serviceB
    configuration.json
    IConfiguration.ts
    ...
/terraform
  ...
```

The interfaces contain a field used in the services, e.g.

```
interface IConfiguration {
  filedFromConfigurationJson1: string;
  filedFromConfigurationJson2: string;
  fieldFromTerraformOutput: string
  // ...
}
```

But in the configuration.json I have:

```
{
  "filedFromConfigurationJson1": "xyz",
  "filedFromConfigurationJson2": "abc"

  // An additional field that is not in the interface, but is passed to terraform. E.g. the name of the service
  "serviceName": "serviceA"

}
```

Field: fieldFromTerraformOutput is terraform output and I can only specify them through the environment variable in cloud run for example (this is a url from another service for example)

```
resource "google_cloud_run_service" ...
name: // name from configuration.json by jsondecode(file(''))
containers {
  env {
    name = "FIELD_FROM_TERRAFORM"
    value = //
  }
}
```

Do you know of any better solution? Somehow it makes more sense to keep the configuration in one place?

Comment: `jsondecode(file("/full/path/.../config.json")).serviceName` that should do it for you